# Initializing date format

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am reading birthdates from a file. They are the format 2-Aug-83, 11-Jun-03. Is there a way to read these in and change the format to the default DD/MM/YYYY? This is the idea, but it is not syntactically valid, clearly. I have found so little online on using date masks and it stumps me each time that I encounter non-default date formats in data. (I wish I could make a stronger attempt but I am at a loss on how to begin.)

Here is the idea of what I want to do:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE dBirthday AS DATE FORMAT "DD-MON-YY".

dBirthday = 2-AUG-80.

DISPLAY dBirthday FORMAT "DD/MM/YYYY".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off by reading it às a character variable and then parsing it as an Openedge date format.

So this

```
dBirthday = 2-AUG-80.
```

wouldn't work because it's not how the date format works. You could do something along the lines of

```
dBirthday = fParseOracleDate("2-AUG-80").

FUNCTION fParseOracleDate RETURNS DATE (cDate AS CHARACTER):
   DEF VAR iMonth AS INT.
   CASE ENTRY(2, cDate, '-'):
      WHEN 'Jan' THEN ASSIGN iMonth = 1.
      /* all months here */
   END CASE.
   RETURN DATE(iMonth, INT(ENTRY(1, cDate,'-')), INT(ENTRY(3, cDate, '-'))).
END FUNCTION.
```

Sorry for the sloppy code, typing on my phone.

Comment: You can replace the CASE statement with a variable + LOOKUP function:  DEF VAR cMonths AS CHARACTER INITIAL "Jan,Feb,...,Dec". iMonth = LOOKUP(ENTRY(2, cDate, "-"), cMonths).

Comment: Absolutely. I didn't want to add that because I didn't have a compiler in front of me and I didn't remember the lookup order of params. Full disclosure, I'm also too lazy to look it up sometimes, lol. Thanks for chipping in.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions! I have an ancillary question that I run into -- if I am reading in dates that are a valid Progress date format, but not the default MM/DD/YYYY, say YYYY-MM-DD, what is the syntax to use when declaring that variable? Here is my example:

`code`
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttBeneficiaries
      FIELD invNum         AS CHARACTER
      FIELD benDOB        AS DATE FORMAT "YYYY-MM-DD"
.
`code`

Sorry for the formatting, I can't seem to get the code markup right in the comments.

Comment: @Felice you don't need to define the variable any special way. But before you import the data with IMPORT, you will need to set SESSION:DATE-FORMAT to whatever the format is. And reset it to whatever the session uses, afterwards (use a FINALLY block if you can).